# Jmeter and Throughput Shaping Timer - several times in one script

Tags: timer, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have a huge script with seven Thread Group. I used Conccurency Thread Group and Throughput Shaping Timer. I have two questions:

1. Can I use value in Throughput Shaping Timer with dots like, START RPS : 0.01, END RPS: 0.3?
2. How to use Throughput Shaping Timer in CTG several times? For example:
   I have 10 steps. First 5 steps should have RPS from 0.5 to 2 (stepped), steps 6 and 7 RPS from 0.3 to 0.8 and last steps, start RPS from 0.1 to 0.4.
   I want to used proportion - my boss want to simulate our production enviroment....

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can.
2. No, you cannot, if you need to apply different throughput values to different Samplers you need to put them into different thread groups as if you put everything into one Thread Group - JMeter will apply the lowest throughput to all the requests due to its threads model nature.

   If you need to pass some data between different thread groups there are 2 options:

   - [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) in first Thread Group to write some value into JMeter Properties and [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in second Thread Group to read the value
   - [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)

Comment: Thank you very much - this is great answer to my quesstions. Thanks again.